# React 17 - Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In tutorials I've seen `this.props` is used for getting props and using them.
When I write this and pass the data is OK but for getting them it shows me this :
*Cannot read property 'props' of undefined*

What's the problem? How can I access them?

```
import '../styles/Navbar.css';

function Navbar() {
    return (
        <h2>{this.props.name} God is dead!</h2>
    );
}

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: constructor(props){
 super(props)
}
Then you can access them by this.props

Comment: @Trizin It doesn't work, I put my code. Please check it again.

Comment: @trizin even in a class component a constructor is not required to use this.props.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your functional component doesn't consume a props object. Add `props` as a parameter to your component. It would also simply be `props` without the `this` ***IN*** the component since functional components are instanceless, `this` is undefined which is the cause for the error.

```
function Navbar(props) {
  return (
    <h2>{props.name} God is dead!</h2>
  );
}
```

With functional components it is also common to destructure the named props in the function signature.

```
function Navbar({ name }) {
  return (
    <h2>{name} God is dead!</h2>
  );
}
```

Or as an arrow function

```
const NavBar = ({ name }) => <h2>{name} God is dead!</h2>;
```

Comment: I'm sending data with link like this. It is not receiving in child component react 17 `<Link to={{pathname: /app/editpan/${pan._id}, search: "?sort=name", hash: "#the-hash", state: { fromDashboard: true } }} underline="none"> {'pan.cardHolder'} </Link>`

Comment: @satendrasingh Seems like this could be a new question/post on SO. This looks like `react-router-dom` link props, so receiving route state depends on the version of `react-router-dom` and how you are accessing the `location` object holding the state. If you like, please post a new question on SO and ping (@ me) here with a link to it and I can take a look at my earliest convenience.

Comment: Thanks and i was find out same solution.